# Java converting string to 2d int array

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream, converters

I have string represention of 2d array i like to convert it to 2d int array
The method i found is cumbersome , what is the best way to do it ?
This is my method :

```
private static int[][] convertMatrix() {

        String mat = "[0, 10, 0, 5, 4],\n" +
                "[1, 3, 10, 2, 8],\n" +
                "[1, 8, 1, 6, 3],\n" +
                "[4, 10, 2, 3, 5],\n" +
                "[9, 0, 9, 1, 0]";

        mat = mat.trim().replaceAll("\\s+","").replaceAll("(?:\\n|\\r)", "");;
        String[] matarr = mat.split("],");
        int[][] matrix = new int[5][5];
        for(int i = 0;i<matarr.length-1;i++) {
            String lineofnumbers = matarr[i].replace("[","");
            String[] lineofnumArr = lineofnumbers.split(",");
            int[] tmp = new int[lineofnumArr.length];
            for(int ii = 0 ; ii < lineofnumArr.length;ii++)
            {
                tmp[ii] = Integer.parseInt(lineofnumArr[ii]);
                //tmp[ii] = ;
            }
            matrix[i] = tmp;
        }
 
        return matrix;
    }
```

i have only java 1.8 support
how can i convert it to version with streams
and version without streams magic ?

Comment: Is this a learning exercise or some other reason for no streams version asked?

Comment: If your code works, Stack Overflow might not be the best place for your question. You might try a Code Review site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to parse a string containing a delimited list of integers arrays, you can try one of two ways:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MatrixParse {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String sampleMatrix = "[0, 10, 0, 5, 4],\n" +
            "[1, 3, 10, 2, 8],\n" +
            "[1, 8, 1, 6, 3],\n" +
            "[4, 10, 2, 3, 5],\n" +
            "[9, 0, 9, 1, 0]";
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(parseWithStream(sampleMatrix)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(parseTraditional(sampleMatrix)));
    }
    
    // JDK 1.8 and higher
    static int[][] parseWithStream(String matrix) {
        return Arrays.stream(matrix.split(",\n"))
            .map(str -> Arrays
                .stream(str.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "")
                    .split("\\s*,\\s*"))
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .toArray())
            .toArray(int[][]::new);
    }
    
    // JDK 1.7 and lower
    static int[][] parseTraditional(String matrix) {
        String[] tokens = matrix.split(",\n");
        int[][] result = new int[tokens.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            String[] subTokens = tokens[i].replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "").split("\\s*,\\s*");
            result[i] = new int[subTokens.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < subTokens.length; j++) {
                result[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(subTokens[j], 10);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

### Result

```
[[0, 10, 0, 5, 4], [1, 3, 10, 2, 8], [1, 8, 1, 6, 3], [4, 10, 2, 3, 5], [9, 0, 9, 1, 0]]
[[0, 10, 0, 5, 4], [1, 3, 10, 2, 8], [1, 8, 1, 6, 3], [4, 10, 2, 3, 5], [9, 0, 9, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Split your input at each comma followed by a new line `,\n` and stream over the resulting array, remove `[` and `]`, map to stream by spliting at comma and space `\\s*,\\s*` and streaming over the resulting array, parse the elements of the stream to int and collect each sub stream to array, and finally collect the arrays to a 2d-array.

```
int[][] result = Arrays.stream(mat.split(",\n"))
                       .map(str -> str.replaceAll("\\[|\\]",""))
                       .map(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s*,\\s*")))
                       .map(arr -> arr.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray())
                       .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Comment: Thanks , what about doing it without streams ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with using the Streams API is like so:

```java
int[][] ints = Arrays.stream(mat.split(",\n"))      // split rows
        .map(s -> s.substring(1, s.length() - 1))   // remove '[' and ']'
        .map(s -> s.split(", *"))                   // split cols of row
        .map(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr)              // map String array to int array
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .toArray()
        )
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ints));
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 10, 0, 5, 4], [1, 3, 10, 2, 8], [1, 8, 1, 6, 3], [4, 10, 2, 3, 5], [9, 0, 9, 1, 0]]
```

If you don't want to use streams, a good way to start is to replace the `Arrays.stream` calls with for loops.